# Проблемы с раскрытием spinner после внедрения адаптера

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

У меня есть spinner который построен на основе кастомного адаптера, вот его код:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List title, count, ids;
    private LayoutInflater inflter;

    SpinnerAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<String> title, List<String> count, List<Integer> ids) {
        this.title = title;
        this.count = count;
        this.ids = ids;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return title.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);


        TextView titles = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView counts = view.findViewById(R.id.number);
        titles.setText((CharSequence) title.get(i));
        counts.setText((CharSequence) count.get(i));

        Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(ids.get(i)));


        return view;
    }
}
```

вот сам spinner:

```
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter1 = new SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), title1, count1, ids1);
spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter1);
```

столкнулся с очень непонятной проблемой - после того как я прописываю клик по элементу спиннера, то в логах клик проходит, но сам спиннер не может перейти в раскрытое состояние. Грубо говоря,  я могу кликать только по первому элементу списка и все. Если убрать клик по вьюхе то спиннер раскрывается и все нормально. Вот как я обрабатываю клик в адаптере в функции `getView`:

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(ids.get(i)));
            }
        });
```

сам виджет состоит из двух текстовых полей который расположены горизонтально.

**Какие я вижу варианты решения проблемы:**

1. сделать обработку клика по одному из textview и спиннер может будет раскрываться.
2. обрабатывать как-то по-другому клик по элементу спиннера.

### update

1 вариант моего решения не работает.

Заранее спасибо за ценные советы и любую помощь.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, я так понял что можно обработать выбор элемента спиннера только из адаптера, или это не так?

Comment: выбор элемента обрабатывается в `onItemSelected` (как-то так, студия не открыта не посмотрю точнее :) )

Comment: @Jarvis_J, а как мне например получить текст с выбранного элемента, напремир у меня каждый элемент спиннера имеет свой id и как мне получить id выбранного элемента?

Comment: например через `getItemId(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) ` или другую функцию, прописанную в адаптере. Вообще, изначально правильно передавать в спиннер список элементом кастомного класса, который включает в себя всю необходимую информацию. И при выборе позиции спиннера считывать нужную информацию с этого листа

Comment: я передаю в адаптер три списка, в числе которых список с id, но мне пока не очень понятно как получать из адаптера без обработки выбора пункта спиннера из адаптера.

Comment: пропишите в принимающей функции `public long getItemId` `return id.get(i)` (например)

Comment: я не вижу конкретной проблемы, пока всё выглядит как общее незнание принципов работы спиннера. Посмотрите уроки и почитайте гайды, не вижу смысла повторять то, что пишут по работе со спиннером везде

Comment: вероятнее всего да)) просто я только недвано узнал что у спиннера тоже можно прописать свой адаптер, и не совсем хорошо знаю нюансы работы с такими адаптерами. Спасибо что помогли :)

Comment: будет что-то конкретное - задавайте вопрос ;)

Answer (score 1):

А Вы пробовали запускать метод super(); на переопределяемой ф-ии? Если да, то какой результат?

Comment: можете уточнить ответ, потому что не очень понятно?

Comment: я имею ввиду что-то подобное:

@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                super();
                Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(ids.get(i)));
            }

Comment: а в фукнции getView должно быть что-то типа такого - view.setOnClickListener(this) ? или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Не совсем
Вы сейчас переопределяете базовую ф-ию класса, которая называется "onClick". В ней Вы выводите лог (и более ничего), т.е. сам процесс инициализации разворачивания спиннера и не происходит. Его нужно запустить, изначально прописав super.onClick(this); в Вашей переопределяемой ф-ии, что и вызовет разворот спиннера, а затем уже выполнится Ваш лог.

Comment: все-равно не очень понимаю, попробовал сделать implement в адаптере функции, но это я так понимаю немного не то.